# Change Anonymous to Authenticated in WebAPI

Tags: authentication, asp.net-web-api, owin, anonymous

I have a WebAPI that accepts anonymous authentication and I save some information related to this anonymous user in cache.

In the finall step of the web, I want to invite user to register in the App but, without lose the information of the caché.

What is the best option to change anonymous user to authenticated user?

Answer (score 0):

If you web application an asp.Net web API, I suggest that you add an[Authorize] attribute in front of the controller class or the controller action where you want to prevent anonymous access (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute(v=vs.118).aspx).

This is explained here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/authentication-and-authorization-in-aspnet-web-api

To do it in practice, the Visual Studio 2015 / 2017 wizards, when creating an ASP.NET application, ask you question on the kind of authentication you want to enable, and add the necessary code for you, and provision an Azure Active Directory application if you need one.

Comment: Thanks @jean-marc-prieur but I don't have any authorization issues, I need change the anonymous user to logged user without lose claims or cache data

Comment: Ok sorry for my mis-understanding, @Sergio. Then you might want to query claims of the authenticated user, in particular using ClaimsPrincipal.Current for instance ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value.